# What is best supported wrapper for Memcache with Scala

Tags: scala, memcached

Can anyone tell me the best wrapper for using `memcache` with `scala`. So far I have found [memcontinuationed](https://github.com/Atry/memcontinuationed), [shade](https://github.com/monix/shade), and [scalacache](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache).

I'm trying to know

- Is there any better wrapper available to communicate with `memcache` using `scala`?
- Which is the best among existing?

Answer (score 1):

After working on this for quite sometime here are my inputs for using Sala APIs wrappers for Caching.

Here I will be comparing mainly two APIs as I was having compatibility issue while using `memcontinuationed` in my project.

### ScalaCache

- Apache 2.0 License
- Can be used for any other caching server as well (Redis, Guava)
- Easy to write a generic class through which its easily either serialize any data types or scale the any type of server for caching, say for example

  - val cachingServer : Cache[String] = MemcachedCache(HOST , PORT)
  - val cachingServer : Cache[String] = GuavaCache[String]
  - val cachingServer : Cache[String] = RedisCache("host1", 6379)
- Documentation is available [here](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache).

### Shade

- MIT License
- Difficult to scale for other caching servers.
- Need to Implement other “MemcachedCodecs” for serializing any custom data type.
- Documentation is available [here](https://github.com/monix/shade).

Please add your comments below :).